# AngularJS. Multiple conditions in Filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Why my condition doesn't work if I put the first of any condition.

1. I put 100 in the PriceTo => I get all items, where price > 100
2. I put "App" in the Name => nothing changes
   But I should get items where (price > 100) AND (Name contains "App").

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QHtD8/142/

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {name:"Apple",type:"fruit",price:100},
        {name:"Grape",type:"fruit",price:500},
        {name:"Orage",type:"fruit",price:555},
        {name:"Carrot",type:"vegetable",price:1000},
        {name:"Milk",type:"dairy",price:800}
    ];

    $scope.productFilter = function (item) {1
        var result = item.name === $scope.foodName ||
                             item.price >= $scope.priceFrom ||
                   item.price <= $scope.priceTo;
            return result;
        };

}
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Name
    <input ng-model="foodName" /><br>
    Price from
    <input ng-model="priceFrom" /><br>
    Price to
    <input ng-model="priceTo" /><br>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in products | filter:productFilter">
          {{item.name}} - {{item.price}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZU5b.png)

Comment: what is the error? fiddle seems to work fine

Comment: Like in the example image. When I put 100 in the PriceTo I get all items, where price > 100, then I put "App" in the Name and nothing changing. But I have to get items where price > 100 AND where Name contains "App".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong conditions in your filtration function.

Try the following:

```
$scope.productFilter = function (item) {
        var result = (!$scope.foodName || item.name.toLowerCase().includes($scope.foodName.toLowerCase())) && 
                     (!$scope.priceFrom || item.price >= $scope.priceFrom) &&
                     (!$scope.priceTo || item.price <= $scope.priceTo);

        return result;
    };
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QHtD8/146/)

Comment: I see... IF $scope.something EXISTS, then we use the condition.
Right?

Comment: `1` is already there in the question, it doesn't do anything (because of ASI this becomes `if(x) { 1; y(); }`) so it can be removed.

Comment: @ValSaven - right, if you put something in the inputs, only then it will use this condition,

Comment: @Caramiriel - just did this :)